# Tkinter - Window blank with label, but same value in label can be printed

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, label

I've got some code that calculates a users calories. I know that the actual calculation is functioning correctly, because if I get python to just print the result it returns the correct value. However, if I try to display the value through a Tkinter Label module, the window is just blank.

```
    RecommendedCal = 0
    if (gendervar.get() == "Male"):
        RecommendedCal = (10 * weight) + (6.25 * height) - (5 * age) + 5
    elif (gendervar.get() == "Female"):
        RecommendedCal = (10 * weight) + (6.25 * height) - (5 * age) - 161
    TotalCalories = Label(calreco_screen, textvariable=RecommendedCal)
    TotalCalories.pack()
```

Comment: you don't need to use `textvariable`. Just use `text = str(RecommendedCal)`

Answer (score 0):

Did you initiate `RecommendedCal` as a String variable beforehand? 
use a string variable initiated with:

```
RecommendedCal = StringVar()
```

Then use another int/float variable for your logic (here cal_value) 
Then update the label content when appropriate with:

```
RecommendedCal.set(f"{cal_value}")
```